# SOAP - return more than one parameter?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

using soap wsdl, is it possible to return more than one parameter? Or do I always have to only have one single parameter returned, eg String, Integer, Boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soap is protocol to exchange data in xml format between client and server. With in xml you can send as many parameters as you want. If you want to find sample soap wsdls have look at www.xmethods.net.
jvmohan

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are programming a jax-rpc style webservice. You can always send back to the client an object that groups all the data you need.

Here's and [example](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/getstartjaxrpc/) that may help you.

Comment: That's a pretty old example (2002). I guess that technology has evolved in this 10 years.

Comment: yes you guess well, but a simple example with jax-rpc is the same now and 10 years ago.

Comment: Not really sure, but [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/) uses jax-rpc style webservice and there is a lot of difference with yours :). Also, there is a whole set of examples from [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to return Objects . It is not necessary to always return primitive types such as String, int , boolean. 
You can always return an Custom class XYZ , List